# How to get form data from django template language

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, django-templates

I'm new to Django, I'm currently iterate through a filtered QuerySet and post the results as a string on my website using `{{file.filename}}`. I'm having trouble getting that filename from a double click.

```
$('.file').dblclick(function () {
    $.post('/accounts/download/', $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

The HTML I have is

```
{% for file in file_info %}
<p id= {{ file.filename }} class='file'>{{ file.filename }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm confused if setting the id this way is the correct way to get the filename.

My view receives the request:

```
def download(request):
    person = request.user.id
    form = Download_Form(request.POST)
    print form
    file_name = form['file_name'].value()
    print file_name
    return render(request, 'main.html')
```

And the following print statements above are

```
<tr><th><label for="id_file_name">File name:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input id="id_file_name" maxlength="300" name="file_name" type="text" /></td></tr>

None
```

I understand that I can't add `.value()` to `form['file_name']`, but I'm not sure how to retrieve that file data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the name of your POST variable (ie `file_name`) to the page. Try changing that line to:

```
$.post('/accounts/download/', {file_name: $(this).attr('id')});
```

It is also a good idea to use quotation marks for the `id` attributes:

```
<p id="{{ file.filename }}" class="file">{{ file.filename }}</p>
```

Then you can simply access the `file_name` using the `request.POST` dictionary. You don't have to instantiate a Django form:

```
@csrf_exempt
def download(request):
    ...
    print request.POST.get('file_name')
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.  I'm starting to understand django a bit more now!